# List All the Objects in AWS S3 using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the following code snippet for listing objects in a bucket.

```
objectListing = client.listObjects(bucketname);
do{
   for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
         System.out.printf(" - %s (size: %d)\n", objectSummary.getKey(), objectSummary.getSize());
        }
         objectListing=s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
  }while (objectListing.isTruncated());
```

I am not able to get the last batch of objects.I did some research regarding this and the batches are being saved in list.But I am not able to use list to save all the objects as there are million of objects and this will cause the heap memory problem sometimes.How can i get all the objects.Thanks!!!

New:

I am running this:

```
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("foo", "bar");
    client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:" + port, null))
    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
    .withChunkedEncodingDisabled(true)
    .build();
    ObjectListing listing = client.listObjects( "bucketname");
    System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
    System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
    System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(999).getKey());
    while (listing.isTruncated()) {
              System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        listing = client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
        System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
        System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
        System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(1000).getKey());
}
```

I am getting following result:

```
Listing size 1000
At 0 index folder1/a.gz
At 999 index folder1/b.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------
Listing size 1001
At 0 index folder1/b.gz
At 1000 index folder1/d.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------
Listing size 1001
At 0 index folder1/d.gz
At 1000 index folder1/e.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and Straightforward

```
ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();

while (listing.isTruncated()) {
   listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
   summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
}
```

Or

```
ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
doSomeProcessing(listing);

while (listing.isTruncated()) {
   listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
   doSomeProcessing(listing);
}
```

Update:
On the below comment of repeating elements, I ran below code

> Yeah,I am getting objects but the 1000 and 1001 objects are repeating
>   and so 2001 and 2002 objects are repeating and so on.How can i avoid
>   this by second method @raevilman. Thank You

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("start");
        ObjectListing listing = s3Client.listObjects( "emr-logs");
        System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
        System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
        System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(999).getKey());
        while (listing.isTruncated()) {
            if(i>3)break;
            System.out.println("========================================================================");
            listing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
            System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
            System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
            System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(999).getKey());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
```

I got the below results, without repeating elements

```
start
Listing size 1000
At 0 index j-10HD9DMBVVTJL/containers/application_1507189355052_0001/container_1507189355052_0001_01_000001/stderr.gz
At 999 index j-156WGS0LMKA2I/node/i-00085367e194fc02a/daemons/instance-state/instance-state.log-2017-11-16-05-15.gz
========================================================================
Listing size 1000
At 0 index j-156WGS0LMKA2I/node/i-00085367e194fc02a/daemons/instance-state/instance-state.log-2017-11-16-05-30.gz
At 999 index j-182UIXOOU8GZ6/node/i-061ffd1d1ae11da74/provision-node/0d1707a0-71dd-4dd5-a1dc-ab226ee2d150/stdout.gz
========================================================================
Listing size 1000
At 0 index j-182UIXOOU8GZ6/node/i-061ffd1d1ae11da74/provision-node/apps-phase/stderr.gz
At 999 index j-1BW9J554DDY15/containers/application_1521803257216_0002/container_1521803257216_0002_01_000002/stderr.gz
========================================================================
Listing size 1000
At 0 index j-1BW9J554DDY15/containers/application_1521803257216_0002/container_1521803257216_0002_01_000002/stdout.gz
At 999 index j-1EKRPTSEXCTB5/node/i-0576a3c452d00384b/applications/hadoop/steps/s-2B5LZ2PC741FD/controller.gz
========================================================================
Listing size 1000
At 0 index j-1EKRPTSEXCTB5/node/i-0576a3c452d00384b/applications/hadoop/steps/s-2B5LZ2PC741FD/stderr.gz
At 999 index j-1G6AYY5EMTR94/node/i-02363f6ac11c89135/daemons/instance-state/instance-state.log-2017-10-29-14-15.gz
end

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: List is being used to save object summaries every time u run and all is being saved in summaries list.I cant use list to save millions of million @raevilman

Comment: Ok. In that case, you can process summaries inside while loop instead of adding it to a list....

Comment: Yeah,I am getting objects but the 1000 and 1001 objects are repeating and so 2001 and 2002 objects are repeating and so on.How can i avoid this by second method @raevilman. Thank You

Comment: I ran the code. But didn't get repeating elements. Updated the answer. Please have a look and suggest if needed any changes.

Comment: I used your sample code with my s3 credentials even though i am getting repeating elements.I am not knowing why.Is there will be any difference in AmazonS3 s3Client connection or something @raevilman Thank You.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the code and output you are running?

Comment: I noticed, in your case, listing size is 1001 is subsequent requests...

Comment: please guide...... I don't k know the purpose of .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:" + port, null))

Comment: The AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration has two fields:
EndpointConfiguration(String serviceEndpoint(http://example.com:port), String signingRegion). Why is the size is 1001 subsequent requests? @raevilman

Comment: Byt what&#39;s the reason behind using endpoint configuration? I am using withRegion in place of that.....about size, strange no idea....

Comment: I keep those double asterisk as previous batch last object and next batch object are same and repeats.It is taking previous batch object into nextbatchlistofobjects and then its is giving 1000 from there including lastbatch last object @raevilman.The endpoint configuration is to access particular host.

Comment: Also if you are getting 1001 objects then 999 index isn't returning the last one..... Is the output forged by you  ..... Screenshot?

Comment: Ok and about endpoint configuration? Why that instead of withRegion method?

Comment: I can print 1000 index but i didnt print as I just ran ur code @raevilman to show just it is getting 1001 and to show it is taking last batch object.The endpoint configuration is to access particular host with port.